# VS2011 - cannot debug javascript Metro style app

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have Windows 8 Consumer Preview and VS2011 Ultimate, not Express.  All I want to do is stop at a breakpoint in the default.js script file.  I created a project from the Split layout template and just ran it.  My javascript debugger console says:

> Visual Studio is not currently attached to a script debug target that
>   supports browser diagnostics.

I am in debug mode, with Script only debugging configuration.  I cannot get any project, including the samples from MSDN to JS debug.  Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I'm having a problem similar to that. You might want to give a look at this msdn topic: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/toolsforwinapps/thread/22357a51-e1e5-4178-88fb-7e014593dcd4

Comment: Did you install Windows 8 on top of Windows 7 or did you nuke everything and install Windows 8 fresh? We're tracking the same issue and that's the only delta so far, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle of any Metro APP is controlled by the PLM. Whenever a metro app is  waiting for a user action the PLM suspends it after a certain timeout. So normal debugging tools may not be useful with the PLM controlling the life cycle of the app. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441481%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a detailed description